# Firefox = Render the Web-Page to an image file

Tags: java, javascript, image, firefox

what is the current "state of art" to render a webpage in firefox into an image file (saved on disk). I want to implement something like "browsershots.org"

1.) Does firefox provide some API to interact with it?

2.) Does the new Canvas (HTML5) Element help here?

The programming language does not matter.

If you know any more information about this topic or a concrete solution, please help.

Uupdate: Yes, the Idea is to do this programatically, only using Technologies "within" Firefox. Further Ideal requirements: Multithreaded (allow rendering of several Websites in parallel on one machine)

Thanks very much, Markus

Comment: Since this isn't about firefox I'm not making this an answer. Check out http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/. It's exactly what you're describing, but uses webkit.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks! Befor posting I already found this library. It looks good. I do not have any clue about CPP (cutycapt is implemented in cpp) so if theres a solution completely and (ideally directly in Firefox) that is easy to implement that would be ideal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> update: Yes, the Idea is to do this
>   programatically, only using
>   Technologies "within" Firefox.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#Rendering_Web_Content_Into_A_Canvas

> Mozilla's canvas is extended with the
>   drawWindow() method. This method draws
>   a snapshot of the contents of a DOM
>   window into the canvas.

Sounds good, but note that:

> This feature is only available for
>   code running with Chrome privileges.
>   It is not allowed in normal HTML
>   pages. [**Read why.**](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/content/canvas/src/nsCanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp#2352)

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel?

Fireshot does exactly that: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/

Even if you want to implement that yourself, looking at that add-on might help.

Comment: I think the point is that the OP wanted to do it programatically (from java if the tags are accurate)

Comment: But still looking how they did it in fireshot might help

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) is a good choice.

It allows you to control Firefox (and other browsers) using Java (for instance).

For example:

http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/examples/capturing-screenshots-from-remote-selenium-rc/

Comment: Thanks very much. Regarding Selenium. Befor Posting I already read their homepage. There are solutions for using selenium for screenshotting, but it seems it is not really multithreaded? At least that was my conclusion?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but you should take a look at [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/). You might not even need it, you should just be able to run multiple Selenium RC instances. And you won't need actual separate machines.